# Is there a functional model of the human retina for simulation of conversion of illuminance pattern to nerve signals?

Tags: theoretical-biology, vision, human-eye

I'm looking for a model that would take a pattern of spectral irradiance over the retina as a function of time and space and convert this into the signals propagating through the fibers of the optic nerve.

I know that there's a variation in distribution of different kinds of receptors over the retina among humans and even between two eyes of a single human, just as there's a variation in the interconnections between the receptors and the outgoing nerve fibers. But I'm interested in a "typical" arrangement that would let me study more general properties of the sensor side of human vision, such as finding different illuminance patterns that yield the same signals after a period of adaptation, or studying how photopic vs scotopic level of illuminance of a scene affects the output signals.

Basically, I'm looking for a black box that would function just as a human retina in terms of input and output.

Is there such a simulator available? If not, has the function of the retina been studied thoroughly enough that I could find a book with enough information to create such a simulator?